# change multiview active index when select dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, multiview

> I made **AutoPostBack="true"** then it was working... but it went to
>   page load and does not happen What I want..
>
> How can I fix this ?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSav_TransferType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbSav_TransferType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem>---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Own Account</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Third Party</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void cmbSav_TransferType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbSav_TransferType.SelectedValue == "Own Account") 
        {
            multiview_AccountTransfer.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        }

        if (cmbSav_TransferType.SelectedValue == "Third Party")
        {
            multiview_AccountTransfer.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what should happen and what is actually happening?  Otherwise we have to make assumptions, and could be wrong.

Comment: when Select 'own account' from drop down list one view should appear. and when select 'Third party' another view should appear..

Comment: Do you mean that the `SelectedIndexChanged` function never executes?  Or that `Page_Load` executes first?  `Page_Load` always executes on postback:  event handlers happen after that.